# "the prince’s late mother’s iconic image"

Tags: adjective-position

I read the following from *the Vanity Fair*:

> Nearly a quarter century after Princess Diana famously sat on a bench now named after her, William and Kate re-enacted **the prince’s late mother’s iconic image** and took their places in front of the monument dedicated to love.

I understand that what the writer meant was 'Princess D's late image.' I am just not sure though if it sounds natural to say 'the prince's late mother's iconic image.': it seems a bit ambiguous to me.

Can anyone suggest an idea about it?

Comment: What other interpretation do you find possible?

Comment: Try *The sixth sick sheik's sixth sheep's sick*!

Comment: The only ambiguity I can think of is that it sounds like it was a picture (of something) that Diana owned, rather than a picture of her.

Comment: @deadrat If I didn't know who Princess Diana was, I could have been confused whether someone's dead mom's image or someone's mom's image of her late years they re-enacted. Is it a nonsense?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you!! I have not thought about it!!

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I should!!

Comment: The sentence could be better phrased as: 'Nearly a quarter century after Princess Diana famously sat on a bench now named after her, William and Kate *re-created* this iconic image of the prince's late mother by taking their places in front of the monument dedicated to love.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i don't see anything wrong with the sentence or the expression in general, but there is a lot of unnecessary repetition. They could have replaced 'the prince's late mother' with 'Princess Diana', and they could have removed iconic. But, it is not an intrinsically wrong statement. After all, they are a newspaper (or magazine). They'll do their best to get your attention by beefing up the language and using unnecessary repetition.

Comment: Thank you!! You are right, I think I felt it was a bit labored and complicated because of the repititions.

Comment: But that would not have underlined the fact that William was the son of Diana, who sat on the seat. And that symbolic fact was the critical point which the writer was trying to get across.